# Linux Glob Pattern to remove all files containing a '?'?

Tags: linux, glob

I would like to descend into a directory and recursively remove all filenames that contain a `?`.

I `wget`ed a website and files of the form `index.html?p=46` were downloaded..extra marks for why this was.

I tried:

```
rm -R *?*
```

that failed: removed all regular files

```
rm -R *\?*
```

also failed: `No such file of directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `find . -iname '*\?*' -exec rm {} \;`

```
$ ls
xxy  x?y

$find . -iname '*\?*'
./x?y
$ find . -iname '*\?*' -exec rm {} \;
$ ls
xxy
```

As for why it happened, the website you wgetted had links to index.html passing those parameters and you (presumably) told wget to mirror it.

Answer (score 0):

`?` maps to single character. You need to escape it:

```
$ touch a a?a
$ ls *?*
a  a?a
$ ls *\?*
a?a
```